# Write windows alt characters in cmd

Tags: cmd.exe, special-characters, escape-characters

I want to write a non-space wrap (it's not a full space, just a tiny space alike character) ALT + 0157. The problem is in windows its ok I can rename a file and add that character to it but in cmd, it shows me `?` instead of .
Anyone knows a way to fix this? I want to rename a file from cmd and add ALT+0157 to it. Or if you any other characters do the same for me please tell.

Comment: I think that this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line - is the article that you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-to-use-unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line - is the article you need, - it appears to give a good overview of character sets and unicode usuable in a command-line environment. Also, please accept my apologies for the comment and the reply, - the site does not allow comments to be edited, expanded on, or deleted.

Comment: I used `chcp 65000` and fixed my problem

Comment: Please edit your answer to be complete and self contained, following our guidelines at [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Sorry, - I did not do that because most forums have a policy regarding "re-inventing the wheel," and would potentially ban users for copy-pasting someone else's work from another forum thread when it could simply be linked (especially bearing in mind that that is part and parcel of the internet and the purpose of links).